# near- rank - deficiency property

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, integration, random-matrices, matrix-equations

I am trying to understand low rank approximations and when I was reading up on it, it is stated that one of the methods of getting the low rank approximation is the near-rank-deficiency property holds true for integral equation methods such as laplacian problems. I dont know what the near-rank-deficiency term means.

Comment: I think I know the answer, the Laplacian operator is a smooth operator with the laplacian field defined for a group of points close to each other is indistinguishable at a distance far away from the group. Hence the matrix representing this system has linearly dependent vectors. I think near-rank deficiency represents the case where the columns are all nearly linearly dependent.